# Who can clarify the the usage of "anyone and everyone"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I read the following "anyone and everyone" sentences but I don't understand why anyone and everyone are used together. Hope anyone can clarify for me. Thanks.

Everyone knows they love to talk on the phone to **anyone and everyone**.

**Anyone and everyone** is to speak to you on the phone.

You will speak to **anyone and everyone** who might list.

Comment: It is used for emphasis, and that is all there is to it.

Answer (score 6):

**Anyone and everyone** is an *exaggeration* which indicates that no matter who it is they qualify.

For your first example the person stating that is simply saying that "they" will talk to anyone who can be bothered to listen. It doesn't matter if they're complete strangers, in the middle of something important, or a telemarketer. If they're on the phone this person will talk to them.

Answer (score 1):

The second and third sentences aren't good examples. I don't think anyone would use the phrase like that.

In the first sentence, it can be interpreted fairly literally. "Everyone knows they love to talk on the phone to *anyone* and *everyone*." *Anyone* because it doesn't matter if it's the president or a McDonald's worker. *Everyone* because they aren't just *willing* to talk to anyone, but they *will* talk to everyone (an exaggeration).

Answer (score 0):

It's a figurative expression meaning "indiscriminately", in a random, unsystematic manner, lacking judgement or selectivity... haphazardly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).